# Using the Dredge function in RMARK

Tags: r

I'm using RMark to calculate nest success vs. 8 covariates.

My data looks like:

```
1) Year
2) Julian Day Egg Lay Date
3) Proportion of Eggs Layed
4) Of eggs Layed, Proportion of Eggs Hatched
5) Mean ibutton Temp Before Hatching
6) Max iButton Temp Before Hatching
7) Mean Te Before Hatching
8) Max Te Before Hatching
```

Nest Survival Group=1 ;
32 2 8 8 0 11 2016 152 1 0.5 30.56 60.5 33.46 71.11 ;

I'm trying to use the dredge function to do all possible combinations.

My code to do single predictor vs. response varable:

```
library(RMark)
hatch = scan("C:.../mark file hatch Julian-150forR.inp", what = "character", sep = "\n")  #to find the file
write(sub(";", "", hatch[13:56]), "hatch.txt")
hatch = read.table("hatch.txt")
names(hatch) = c("id", "FirstFound", "LastPresent", "LastChecked", "Fate", "Freq", 
    "Year", "LayDate", "PropLayed", "PropHatch", "MeaniButtn", "MaxiButtn", "MeanTe", 
    "MaxTe")
run.hatch = function() {
    Dot = mark(hatch, nocc = 58, model = "Nest", model.parameters = list(S = list(formula = ~1)))
    Year = mark(hatch, nocc = 58, model = "Nest", model.parameters = list(S = list(formula = ~Year)))
    LayDate = mark(hatch, nocc = 58, model = "Nest", model.parameters = list(S = list(formula = ~LayDate)))
    PropLayed = mark(hatch, nocc = 58, model = "Nest", model.parameters = list(S = list(formula = ~PropLayed)))
    MeaniButtn = mark(hatch, nocc = 58, model = "Nest", model.parameters = list(S = list(formula = ~MeaniButtn)))
    MaxiButtn = mark(hatch, nocc = 58, model = "Nest", model.parameters = list(S = list(formula = ~MaxiButtn)))
    MeaniTe = mark(hatch, nocc = 58, model = "Nest", model.parameters = list(S = list(formula = ~MeanTe)))
    MaxTe = mark(hatch, nocc = 58, model = "Nest", model.parameters = list(S = list(formula = ~MaxTe)))
    return(collect.models())
}
hatch.results = run.hatch()
```

When I try to use the `dredge` function, here's my code:

```
require(MuMIn)
run.hatch = function() {
    global <- Dot = mark(hatch, nocc = 58, model = "Nest", model.parameters = list(S = list(formula = ~1))) + 
        Year = mark(hatch, nocc = 58, model = "Nest", model.parameters = list(S = list(formula = ~Year))) + 
        LayDate = mark(hatch, nocc = 58, model = "Nest", model.parameters = list(S = list(formula = ~LayDate))) + 
        PropLayed = mark(hatch, nocc = 58, model = "Nest", model.parameters = list(S = list(formula = ~PropLayed))) + 
        MeaniButtn = mark(hatch, nocc = 58, model = "Nest", model.parameters = list(S = list(formula = ~MeaniButtn))) + 
        MaxiButtn = mark(hatch, nocc = 58, model = "Nest", model.parameters = list(S = list(formula = ~MaxiButtn))) + 
        MeaniTe = mark(hatch, nocc = 58, model = "Nest", model.parameters = list(S = list(formula = ~MeanTe))) + 
        MaxTe = mark(hatch, nocc = 58, model = "Nest", model.parameters = list(S = list(formula = ~MaxTe))) + 
        return(collect.models())
}
combinations <- dredge(global)


> Error in nobs(global.model) : object 'global' not found
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is something very wrong with your code: `global <- Dot = mark(...) + return(...)` does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

You define `global` within the scope of function `run.hatch`. It is invisible outside of it. Besides, `run.hatch` is supposed to return a list of models, while `dredge` expects just one model. For example:

```
global <- mark(...)
combinations <- dredge(global)
```

Comment: Thank you!        Any ideas how I can modify my code so that I can run all possible models?

Comment: You need to formulate a "maximum model" and feed it to `dredge`. Just like in the example above.